# numpy argmin() of sliced array return original index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array

```
print(a)
> array([   0.        ,  341.59065809,  215.33694527,  586.00085324])
```

and when I slice it and try to take the argmin()

```
print(a[1,3])
> array([ 341.59065809,  586.00085324])
print(a[1,3].argmin())
> 0
```

However I want to get the index of the original array (ie. 1). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `argmin` output to index into your original array of indices (i.e `[1,3]`)

```
    a = array([   0.        ,  341.59065809,  215.33694527,  586.00085324])
    elems = [1,3]
    min_ind = elems[a[elems].argmin()] #1
```

Comment: I feel so dumb.